# Regular expression to validate field structure

Tags: grep

I would like to implement a regular expression in linux that using grep allows me to verify that a field contains 15 numerical values and that the value occupying the fifth position (starting from left) is either a 5 or a 6.

I have reached the point of defining the requirement that it contains a maximum of 15 values, however, I can not get that the one that occupies the fifth position is a 5 or 6. It would be:

```
grep -E "^[0-9]{1,15}"
```

Any idea?

Comment: Can you give some examples that the wanted regular expression would match? Right now it seems like this might work: `^[0-9]{4}(5|6)[0-9]{10}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For exactly 15 numbers, and the 5 position is either 5 or 6:

```
grep -E "^[0-9]{4}[56][0-9]{10}$"
```

- `^` Start of string
- `[0-9]{4}` Match 4 digits
- `[56]` Match either `5` or `6`
- `[0-9]{10}` Match 10 digits
- `$` End of string

To match at least the first 5 characters followed by 0-10 digits after it, and allow a partial match like matching `123462222233333` in `12346222223333344444`

```
grep -Eo "^[0-9]{4}[56][0-9]{0,10}"
```